# Bootstrap datepicker adjust position and size on small browser screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

My Bootstrap datepicker  currently displays at the bottom left of the textbox, thats ok in a normal browser window. But the issue comes when the browser window is made small or resized. I want to make the datepicker display top left when the browser window is made small . Also on small screen I want the datepicker to become small also , but it should be readable and should also look good

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: orientation: 'auto' shoud do it https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#orientation

Comment: we already have  
             orientation: "bottom auto",
But its not working. The datepicker is inside bootstrap modal. When make the size smaller it cuts off the datepicker from the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You want to use CSS media queries for different resolutions. eg.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .some-class {
        float: right;
        width: some_width;
        height: auto;
    }     
}

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .some-class {
        float: left;
        width: some_smaller_width;
        height: auto (or some specific height);
    }
}
```

more: [w3schools/mediaqueries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)